# SQL How to display all columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

at start sorry for my english. I have problem, because I don't know how display all columns from my table. I have a simple database with 2 tables.
[Table Recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY8Hv.png) 
[Table Aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76aBx.png)
In columns Aggregate_no_1_ID, Aggregate_no_2_ID, Aggregate_no_3_ID I want display a Aggregate_color from aggregate table.

I try something like that, but each rows is displayed 3 times.
[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxhz.png)
I expect a result like on the photo bellow.
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvBGX.png)

Comment: In the future, please do not post links to images. Just plain text in the question body is better. Tables can be formatted with the markdown syntax.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on this forum, I thought that the photo would be pasted in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a sequence of joins rather than unions?

```
select rcp.id,
       agg1.aggregate_color as color_a,
       agg2.aggregate_color as color_b,
       agg3.aggregate_color as color_c,
       rcp.aggregate_no_1_weight,
       rcp.aggregate_no_2_weight,
       rcp.aggregate_no_3_weight
  from recipez10 rcp
  left
  join aggregate as agg1
    on rcp.aggregate_no_1_id = agg1.id
  left
  join aggregate as agg2
    on rcp.aggregate_no_2_id = agg2.id
  left
  join aggregate as agg3
    on rcp.aggregate_no_3_id = agg3.id
```